# Mod_Proxy 502-Proxy Error intermittently

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, tomcat7, mod-proxy

I'm Using Apache 2.2.16 and Tomcat 7.0.16. I have 3 Tomcat instance which executes 3 different war files. To bypass the request I have configured httpd with mod_proxy.

3 Tomcat instances are running in 8080, 8090, 8099. find the httpd configuration below

```
ProxyPass /bor `http://localhost:8080/bor/
ProxyPass /borcafews/ `http://localhost:8090/borcafews/
ProxyPass /borechws/ `http://localhost:8099/borechws/
```

Intermittently I was getting 502 Proxy Error in 8090 and 8099. So I have set the below variables in the httpd.conf

```
<Location /borcafews/>
SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
</Location>`
```

After setting this configuration the borcafews was not giving any Proxy Error but for borechws is failing with 502-Proxy Error intermittently.

`proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /borechws/services/bor (20014)Internal error: proxy: error reading status line from remote server localhost:8099`

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is an error in your Apache config: It is entirely possible your tomcat app returns a wrong answer.

Use tcpdump or tshark to capture the traffic on the relevant ports.  This will verify your tomcat application is returning valid HTTP Responses.